# obfuscated way to get "0" in a tcl function, cross platform?

Tags: testing, obfuscation, tcl

I haven't used tcl before and just need to do one trick, I can do it trivially in something like bash but I need it to work cross-platform (e.g. tcl in cygwin  on windows).

Can someone suggest a short (5-10) obfuscated function that just returns 0 after taking two string args? It just can't do something like run shell commands that won't work under Mac/Cygwin.

fwiw, why do this: buying some time in writing a test- the thing generating one of the files is broken but I can't change it, making a hack in the TCL test script until I make extensive changes to use a different 'test core' that isn't broken. For now just declare the first file as 'good' if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the requirement for obfuscation, but the simplest way to create a command that takes two arguments and returns `0` is this:

```
proc theCommandName {firstArgument secondArgument} {
    return 0
}
```

There are all sorts of ways of making things obscure (e.g., a regular expression that doesn't actually match anything, a complicated expression) but as I said before, I don't understand the requirement in that area; I always try to make my code be the simplest thing that could possibly work…

Comment: BTW, the above code snippet and ideas are totally cross-platform because they don't do anything at all with the OS. Every Tcl interpreter will be able to handle them.

Comment: "a regular expression that doesn't actually match anything" good idea... was just worried about cross-platform.

Its a 'political/bureaucratic' thing unfortunately. I'm getting complaints about an auto-tester failing on certain platforms because binary files aren't identical, but its not my code's fault, its the way the writer does round-off before printing to XML. So I wanted to just make the test always pass to buy some time, then find a different way to compare files. Its a bunch of work because the feature I'm adding doesn't have an industry-standard file writer, etc etc...

Comment: @peter: You have my sympathy. If you're using `tcltest` to manage the testing, you can add custom matching modes so that you can better control what “equal” means (e.g., floats that are equal within epsilon).